# In cygwin, Disable // type samba path

Tags: cmake, cygwin

I use CMake and its FindPackage. The FindPackage often is used something like //usr/local/lib. But the Cygwin solve a // is a samba path. So, Its cases are CMake errors.

I would like to disable // type samba path on Cygwin.

Regards.

---

I call FindOpenCV, FindQtCore, and FindECM (Extra CMake Modules).
For example, there are error messages of FindOpenCV on Cygwin as below.

```
CMake Error at /lib/cmake/opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake:124 (message):
  The imported target "opencv_core" references the file

     "//lib/libopencv_core.dll.a"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/lib/cmake/opencv/OpenCVModules.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /lib/cmake/opencv/OpenCVConfig.cmake:71 (include)
  util/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

There messages are caused on OpenCVModules.cmke. (A script is called at line 112 in OpenCVModule.cmake , and OpenCVModule.cmake is called at line 71 in OpenCVConfig.cmake.)
For example, OpenCVModule-relwithdebinfo.cmake is as below.

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "RelWithDebInfo".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Import target "opencv_core" for configuration "RelWithDebInfo"
set_property(TARGET opencv_core APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELWITHDEBINFO)
set_target_properties(opencv_core PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELWITHDEBINFO "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libopencv_core.dll.a"
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES_RELWITHDEBINFO ""
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/bin/cygopencv_core-2.4.dll"
  )

list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS opencv_core )
list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_opencv_core "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libopencv_core.dll.a" "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/bin/cygopencv_core-2.4.dll" )
```

There is script that find the /lib/opencv_core.dll.a. 
If _IMPORT_PREFIX is /, it would find //lib/opencv_core.dll.a.
In this case, //lib/opencv_core.dll.a becomes \lib\opencv_core.dll.a in the Windows path.
Of course. It becomes error because the server named "lib" doesn't exist.

Comment: `The FindPackage often is used something like //usr/local/lib` - please, provide an example. `find_package()` mostly just call `FindXXX.cmake` or `XXXConfig.cmake`, so the problem could be with those scripts.

Comment: I show to above because an example is too longer.
Are you okay with this example?

Comment: Yes, with given example the problem is perfectly clear now. [From my point of view, the question itself is good; downvotes are not from me.] However, I don't know the answer. [They said](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Cygwin-drive-paths-are-killing-me-td7587631.html), there is special CMake build for cygwin. May be it solves some problems. But solving *all problems* with `//` in path seems impossible: CMake has no "join-paths" functionality, so even CMake itself may fix path for libraries, includes,... it cannot fix paths in *arbitrary* command lines produced by the scripts.

Comment: I see. I fix the code by myself. Thank you for giving me advice.